# Workaround for error in RVIZ with a position only robot arm

Tags: ros2, moveit, motion-planning

I am receiving an error in RVIZ when I tell the moveit planner to plan a path for my robot arm to a new random position.  The error is related to velocity limits.  My robot arm implements a position only interface.  I realize that it would be a trivial case for moveit to plan a path from position A to B without velocity information.  My desire is that when I hit the plan and execute button in rviz, the new  position is instantly commanded.  I am using ros2 iron on ubunto 22.04.  Is there a simple workaround for this.  From some example code, my intent was to remove all the velocity information/interface between my arduino robot arm and ros2.

Regards,
Jeff

The error I received is below:

```
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1698242348.017672132] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.018012233] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.018135286] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1698242348.018203786] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.024624491] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.024677721] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.024931838] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'arm' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.



[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1698242348.051046662] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: No velocity limit was defined for joint Joint1! You have to define velocity limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1698242348.051117939] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]:  Time parametrization for the solution path failed.
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1698242348.051134122] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: The planner plugin did not fill out the 'planner_id' field of the MotionPlanResponse. Setting it to the planner ID name of the MotionPlanRequest assuming that the planner plugin does warn you if it does not use the requested planner.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1698242348.051158811] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Motion plan was computed successfully.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1698242348.051447414] [move_group_interface]: Planning request complete!
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1698242348.052304236] [move_group_interface]: time taken to generate plan: 0.00142846 seconds
```

Comment: I think you shoul try to add velocity limits to your joint_limits.yaml. To command just a positioning you should go very deep into moveit implementation details